# Magento 2 empty txt in cron fputcsv

Tags: magento2, cron

I have created a custom module that exports the products in a text file
If I call the method from a view (visiting the browser page) the file is created correctly but if I call method from a custom cron the file is created empty

Here is the function in Altravista\CustomModule\Block;

```
public function getCsvFeed()
{
    $csv_handler = fopen ('feeds/feed.txt','w');

    $csv = array();

    foreach ($this->helper->getProductCollection() as $product) {
        $productId = $product->getId();
        //Name 
        $csv = array($this->helper->getProductName($product));

        ... MY CODE ...


        fputcsv ($csv_handler,$csv,$this->helper->getCsvDelimiter());
            //$csv[] = '';

    } //end foreach

    fclose ($csv_handler);

    $this->_logger->debug('Running Cron from Altravista');
    return $this;
}
```

}

The cron run correctly and print log

Answer (score 0):

```
        public function getCsvFeed()
        {
            $csv_handler = fopen ('feeds/feed.txt','w');

            $csv = array();
            $this->_logger->debug(get_class($this->helper));
            foreach ($this->helper->getProductCollection() as $product) {
                $productId = $product->getId();
                //Name 
                $csv = array($this->helper->getProductName($product));
                $this->_logger->debug('Inside CSV');
                $this->_logger->debug(get_class_methods($this->helper));
                ... MY CODE ...

                try{
                    fputcsv ($csv_handler,$csv,$this->helper->getCsvDelimiter());
                }
                catch(Exception $e){
                echo '<pre>'; 
                 print_r($e->getMessage()); 
                 exit;
                }
                    //$csv[] = '';

            } //end foreach

            fclose ($csv_handler);

            $this->_logger->debug('Running Cron from Altravista');
            return $this;
        }
```